# Ionic framework Mobile Application Size Problems

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed an android mobile application using the Ionic framework.
Now the application contains html pages only[No back end].The application size is about 6.00Mb.The application seems to be working well when opening in Web/Mobile Browser.When we build mobile application,the application becomes very slow and gets flickering. This is resulting in a very poor user experience.

My ionic cli information is,

```
    muhzi@muhzi-Inspiron-5420:~/ionicProject$ ionic info 
    Your system information:
    Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
    Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
    Gulp local:  
    Ionic Version: 1.0.1
    Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
    Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.8
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 
Node Version: v0.12.7
```

I searched a lot.So this issue can resolved by adding crosswalk. I've added crosswalk to a project and have had some serious app size increase[6mb --->59mb]

Also i have followed answer of [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070389/ionic-framework-mobile-application-performance-issue) for improving the performance of ionic application.Still the application size is same.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Could it be CSS and JS performance-issues?

Comment: No.I have Minified all JS and CSS files.Also I used jshint in my project.

Comment: Minifying and JShinting alone aren't the only optimizations you could do. Because we don't see your code or app, it's just speculation. Do you use a  scroll-handler? Do you use animations? How do you animate? Are the animations hardware-accelerated? Is it really just janky/laggy in the app, or also in some browser?

Comment: no i didnt use animations.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this type of behavious happens when you have one or several large images in your application. Where the definition of large image is above 1024x1024. This mainly caused by the hardware accelarion by openGL, which can not handle very big images on Android. (Try adding a 3000x3000 image in a sliding menu and you will see what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

Adding Crosswalk plugin will definitely affect the file size.

To give a rough idea, the HTML/JS/CSS for one of the project's sample applications takes up 24Kb of disk space.

Once this application is packaged with its own Crosswalk 10 (x86 Android) runtime, the apk file size is ~20Mb. Installed, the application takes ~58Mb of disk space.(Source: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html )