# AngularJs Ionic - Display huge amount of text in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-bind-html

One of the client requests was to display legal information in application. Problem is that legal information is about 15 pages of text. I tried to display that, but app is stuck for 10 seconds before showing view (text is pre-loaded, so its not due to network). I'm using ng-bind-html for that
`<p class="item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html="::group.fields.content"></p>`

My guess is that problem happens in ng-bind-html directive.
Obvious solution would be to split text into smaller chunks, but due to design in client CMS that would make managing text inconvenient for client.
Does anyone have advice how to deal with this. I've never encountered this kind of situation.

Comment: maybe try to add point no 1 from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29126440/3033318), it worked for me, improve performance of whole app althouth the size get much biogger

Comment: I'm already using crosswalk. It works fine on Android, but it kills iPad 2